# how to fetch next row when given row is hidden using pagination?

Tags: mysql, ajax, pagination, hide, toggle

It rather hard for me to come up with a short form of my question so bear with me:

Using jQuery and AJAX, I have all posts stored in my MySQL database displaying on index.php. Each post has a button the lets the user hide that post's DIV.

Now, I want to make it so that I only see 10 results and paginate the rest. I know there are plenty of pagination plugins out there but none of them displays the next post when the user hides one of the 10 already shown posts.

So if I see Posts 1-10 on page 1 (posts 11-20 on page 2) and user hides post 8, I should see Posts 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11 on page 1 with posts 12-21 on page 2 and so on.

Question is: How do I do that? Here's what I have right now (fetch posts from database, display posts on page + hide button toggling):

```
// Javascript

$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click", ".hide", function(){
    postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('hide_', '');

    $('#post-' + postID).toggle();

    return false;
});
});


// PHP

<?php
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts"), OBJECT);
?>
<?php if ($pageposts): ?>

<?php global $post; ?>

<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div id="buttons_<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div id="hide_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="hide" style="position:absolute; right: 2.5em;">
                <a id="hidebtn_<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="#"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            /* display post content */
        </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: your problem needs to be solved using MySQL : modify your SQL so that it only lists the ones that the user did not hide and that way it will be easy to get the results you want

Comment: but this is inefficient. Why launch a query every time a post is hidden when I am already displaying all the posts?

Comment: sorry i must have misunderstood when the query is supposed to be called, but Francis' answer should give you a hint :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to figure out what would be the next ID to grab would be to store the MAX id on the page, so if your page displays 1-10, 10 would be stored as the MAX id.
When a user hides a post, the mysql query would pull 1 result where id > the stored max id.

Comment: Not so simple. The posts are in a wordpress database. The posts 1-10 are not necessarily ID 1-10. They could be ID 1,5,20,23,24,25,80... I admit I simplified my query... there is a WHERE clause selecting only posts in a given category. Even if I stored the ID of the last post displayed, there is no way to predict what ID the next post will have. All that being said, finding the next row in the database isn't the problem: pulling the first result from page 2 into the bottom of page 1 while resetting the pagination is the big question.

Comment: You don't have to predict what the next id will be. Even if they are in 1, 5, 20, 23, 24, 25, 80; store 80 as the max id and your query would be WHERE id > 80.

If the results are ordered by something other than the id, store that instead.

Comment: yup i agree with @Francis, and you should not forget to update that maxID once you get a new post

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but what about my pagination? Pulling in the next post is one thing, but then how do I remove that same post from page 2 and reset the pagination?